# Как заменить все выводы на экран обьектами?

Tags: python

Как заменить все выводы на экран объектами так, что бы функция возвращала эти объекты? То есть убрать из кода все print так, чтобы `return` заменял бы их.

```
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def data():
    engine=create_engine('mysql://***********:**************/nova', echo=False)
    connect=engine.connect()

q0 = text(
    "SELECT project_id FROM instance_actions "
    "WHERE user_id LIKE :e0 "
)
users = connect.execute(q0, e0='c88%')
seen=set()
newwlist=[]
for user in users:
    tt=tuple(user)
    if tt not in seen:
        newwlist.append(user)
        seen.add(tt)

leng=len(newwlist)
for i in range(0, leng):
    project_id=newwlist[i][0]
    print "Project:", project_id
    q = text(
        "SELECT instance_uuid FROM instance_actions "
        "WHERE project_id LIKE :e1 "
    )
    instances = connect.execute(q, e1=project_id).fetchall()
    seen=set()
    newlist=[]
    for item in instances:
        t=tuple(item)
        if t not in seen:
            newlist.append(item)
            seen.add(t)
   total[project_id] = {}
   len=len(newlist)
    for i in range(0, len):
        inst_id=newlist[i][0]
        print "Machine:", inst_id
        query = text(
            "SELECT unix_timestamp(created_at), action FROM instance_actions "
            "WHERE instance_uuid LIKE :e2 "
        )
        result = connect.execute(query, e2=inst_id).fetchall()
        for row in result:
            print row


        pozitive=['create', 'start', 'restart', 'reboot', 'unpause']
        negative=['stop', 'pause', 'delete']
        create='create'
        delete='delete'

        starttime = -1
        length = len(result)
        totaltime_1=0

        total[project_id][inst_id] = {}
        total[project_id][inst_id]['totaltime_1'] = []
        for j in range(0, length):
            if result[j][1] in pozitive:
                starttime = result[j][0]
            elif result[j][1] in negative and result[j-1][0] is starttime:
                a = (result[j][0] - starttime) / 3600
                b = (result[j][0] - starttime) % 3600
                if b is 0:
                    time=a
                elif b is not 0:
                    time=a+1
                    print time
                    totaltime_1 += time
                    starttime=-1
        days_1=totaltime_1 / 24
        remaining_hours_1=totaltime_1 % 24
total[project_id][inst_id]['totaltime_1'].append(totaltime_1)            
return {'total' : total}
```

Что нужно написать в `return` чтобы вывод остался тот же, а все `print` можно было бы убрать?

Comment: Переформулируйте вопросы, к сожалению не понятно что вы хотите сделать. print нельзя заменить при помощи return. print - выводит информацию и их может быть сколько угодно, а return возвращает значение выше стоящему методу, и может быть только один.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Изначально это был код без функции data(), но сейчас мне нужна функция, которая будет возвращать все oбьекты, которые сейчас являются переменными при выводе, (totaltime_1, prioject_id, inst_id). Вопрос в том, как все переменные которые выводяться на экран записать в объект так, чтобы функция возвращала этот объект?

Comment: Создайте словарь total = {}, и записывайте туда вывод, то есть total['project_id'] = project_id, а в return верните total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен что верно расставил отступы, но можно сделать так:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def data():
    total = {}
    engine=create_engine('mysql://***********:**************/nova', echo=False)
    connect=engine.connect()

    q0 = text(
        "SELECT project_id FROM instance_actions "
        "WHERE user_id LIKE :e0 "
    )
    users = connect.execute(q0, e0='c88%')
    seen=set()
    newwlist=[]
    for user in users:
        tt=tuple(user)
        if tt not in seen:
            newwlist.append(user)
            seen.add(tt)

    leng=len(newwlist)
    for i in range(0, leng):
        project_id=newwlist[i][0]
        print "Project:", project_id
        total[project_id] = {}
        q = text(
            "SELECT instance_uuid FROM instance_actions "
            "WHERE project_id LIKE :e1 "
        )
        instances = connect.execute(q, e1=project_id).fetchall()
        seen=set()
        newlist=[]
        for item in instances:
            t=tuple(item)
            if t not in seen:
                newlist.append(item)
                seen.add(t)
        len=len(newlist)
        for i in range(0, len):
            inst_id=newlist[i][0]
            print "Machine:", inst_id
            total[project_id][inst_id] = {}
            query = text(
                "SELECT unix_timestamp(created_at), action FROM instance_actions "
            "WHERE instance_uuid LIKE :e2 "
        )
            result = connect.execute(query, e2=inst_id).fetchall()
            for row in result:
                print row

            pozitive=['create', 'start', 'restart', 'reboot', 'unpause']
            negative=['stop', 'pause', 'delete']
            create='create'
            delete='delete'

            starttime = -1
            length = len(result)
            totaltime_1=0

            total[project_id][inst_id]['totaltime_1'] = []
            for j in range(0, length):
                if result[j][1] in pozitive:
                    starttime = result[j][0]
                elif result[j][1] in negative and result[j-1][0] is starttime:
                    a = (result[j][0] - starttime) / 3600
                    b = (result[j][0] - starttime) % 3600
                    if b is 0:
                        time=a
                    elif b is not 0:
                        time=a+1
                        print time
                        totaltime_1 += time
                        starttime=-1
            days_1=totaltime_1 / 24
            remaining_hours_1=totaltime_1 % 24
            total[project_id][inst_id]['totaltime_1'].append(totaltime_1)
return total
```

Comment: Проверьте, точно ли "for i in range(0, leng)" leng не равно 0, и точно ли id проектов не совпадают.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
def data():
    total = {}
    ...
    leng=len(newwlist)
    for i in range(0, leng):
        project_id=newwlist[i][0]
        total[project_id] = {}
        ...
        total[project_id]['inst_id'] = []
        len=len(newlist)
        for i in range(0, len):
            inst_id=newlist[i][0]
            total[project_id]['inst_id'].append(inst_id)
            ...
    ...
    return total
```

Comment: Работает, толко выводит одно значение project_id и одно inst_id, а должно 2 значения project_id и очень много inst_id. Не выполняються for цыклы.

Comment: Если хотите несколько значений добавить, то сделайте так: total['inst_id'] = [], а потом в цикле, total['inst_id'].append(inst_id)

Comment: Соответственно для project_id аналогично.

Comment: выводит все inst_id для одного project_id, а надо для двух project_id

Comment: Обновите код, что у вас получилось.

Comment: Обновлено. Таким образом я получила то что надо проект-instance-время. Все только для одного проекта, а проектов два. Что-то гдето не сходится.